# Multiple User-inputs, Default input, and String-to-Array Conversion

Tags: python, user-input, default-value, string-conversion, multiple-input

Hello all I would like to make a program that takes in two user inputs. The first is a scalar and the second is a provided list or array. The number would be a multiplier for which to scale the array and the output would be the multiplied array.

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
b = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Also, for added convenience to the user, I'd like there to be a default scalar of 1 if no number is entered.

I am sorry for the lack of code but everything I've tried has not worked anyway.

I know that using

```
x, y = input().split()
```

will enable the user to enter two inputs such as

```
3 a
```

or

```
5.5 b
```

which is how I'd like the inputs to be entered. However, while the number can be converted to a float, I do not know how to interpret the letter a or b from a string to the their array names.

```
float(x)*np.array(y)
```

The following error I believe to have occurred due to the mismatch of data types.

```
 float(x)*np.array(y)
TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

If anyone can offer a solution or if there is a better way to do this than your input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you wish to take any list as an input from the user or some pre-defined lists like a and b?

Comment: The lists are predefined. The user would just enter the scalar and the name of the list.

Comment: You should note that you need numpy arrays instead of lists, otherwise multiplication won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this helps!
This also handles the case where the user doesn't specify a multiplier, then it automatically defaults to 1

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
b = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])

y,*x = input().split()
if not x:
    x=[1]

print(float(x[0])*eval(y))
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, do you happen to know if you can set a default value of 1 for the coefficient if no number is entered?

Comment: @Plums I have updated my answer, that solves this issue as well, have a look!

Comment: Thank you! This concludes my question!

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions for your issue, one is cleaner.

The first one (dirty) consists in using `eval`, because the `a` or `b` your user will pass as input will be evaluated as a string, not as your variable named `a`.
So you have to return `float(x) * eval(y)`.

But the use of `eval` is heavily discouraged.

I think a cleaner way is to declare your pre-defined arrays in a `dict` and to look for the key the user provided like that:

```py
import numpy as np

arrays = {
    "a": np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9]),
    "b": np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
}

coefficient, array_name = input().split()

print(float(coefficient) * arrays[array_name])
```

NB: In your original code, `a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]` defines a list. And you cannot multiply a `float` and a list. You could eventually multiply and `int` and a list but that is not what you want, it will duplicate your list :)

Comment: Thank you this answer has greatly helped. However, do you happen to know if you can set a default value of 1 for the coefficient if no number is entered?